# Python Unit Testing in Eclipse only runs one function

Tags: python, eclipse, unit-testing

Hopefully this question has an easy answer. It's probably something stupid I'm doing!

In Eclipse, Run As Python Unit-Test for the following code:

```
import unittest
from ShipClass import *
from Graphics import *

class UnitTesting(unittest.TestCase):
    def testInit(self):
        self.screen = load_screen()
        assert load_background() == True
        print("Here!")

    def spawnShip(self):
        ship = Ship((self.screen.get_rect().x, self.screen.get_rect().y))
        self.screen.blit(ship.image, ship.rect)
        print("Here!")

        assert updateDisplay() == True
```

The code outputs only one "Here!" to the console. It also says, "Ran 1 test...", etc.

Why isn't it running both tests?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python unittest runner uses method name prefixes to find tests. `spawnShip` is not recognised as a test method. To fix that, call it something like `testSpawnShip`